# Polynomial without zero in B

Tags: complex-analysis

### Let $0<r<1$. Show that, for $n$ large enough, polynomial $1+2z+3z^2+...+(n+1)z^n$ has no zeros in $B(0,1).$

I wanna use Rouché theorem and find another function with $|f-g|<|f|$ wherever $|z|=1$. But I have tried some g but no one satisfy. So I was stuck.
Thanks for help!

Comment: The limit of this series as $n\rightarrow\infty$ is $(1-z)^{-2},$ for $|z|<1.$

Comment: Yeah, that way everything is OK. Thanks.